# How do I use string variable (which contains double quote) in grep

Tags: bash, grep

I have the following bash code:

```
DNS_RECORD_NAME="\"_acme-challenge\""
linode-cli domains records-list 1020562 --pretty --json |
            grep '"name": $DNS_RECORD_NAME'
```

The output should be like this:

```
"name": "_acme-challenge"
```

but I got empty result. If I change the following line

```
grep '"name": $DNS_RECORD_NAME"
```

to

```
grep '"name": "_acme-challenge"'
```

I got the correct output.

But I need to use variable. How do I use string variable (which contains double quote) in grep?

Comment: You can use something like `grep "\"name\": $DNS_RECORD_NAME"`

Comment: Thank you so much this work! I thought that this has something to do with grep that doesn't allow variable output. Can you write an answer and I accept yours.

Comment: If you're going to specify the `--json` output format, you should really consider using a JSON tool such as `jq` to select the data of interest. OTOH if you're set on using `grep`, it might be better to stick with the `--text` output format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use single quotes the the pattern is taken as a literal string, so

```
grep '"name": $DNS_RECORD_NAME'
```

will try to match the *literal* string

```
"name": $DNS_RECORD_NAME
```

the variable is not expanded.

For it to work you can:

```
grep "\"name\": $DNS_RECORD_NAME"
```

or

```
grep '"name": '"$DNS_RECORD_NAME"
```

here the variable `$DNS_RECORD_NAME` is expanded.